# how can we retrieve file of remote system using php code

Tags: php

if  we have tree structure of a file that located at the remote system then how can we retrieve that file

Comment: Can you be more specific about the file youre trying to get at and the methods available to you to access the remote system (ie. http, ftp, ssh, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the file system in question. NFS is different to SFTP is different to SMB is different to AFS etc etc.

Your OS might allow you to mount the remote file system onto your main file system (e.g. via FUSE), in which case you just treat it as a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) ? It works for network files. If remote server have http or ftp, you can use curl.